# Python Decimal sum strange behavior

Tags: python, math, decimal

It must be my mistake, but I can't understand what is going on.
Here code with that behavior

in cycle we get value:

```
type of data[name]['money_receive']
is Vividict

 class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
       value = self[key] = type(self)()
       return value
```

So

```
data[name]['money_receive'] = Decimal(1659605.00)
money_receive = data[name]['money_receive'] if data[name]['money_receive'] else Decimal(0.0)


column_sum = {'money_receive': Decimal(0.0)}

column_sum["money_receive"] += money_receive
print u"%s Receive %s" % (money_receive, type(money_receive))
print u"%s Receive All %s" % (column_sum["money_receive"], type(column_sum["money_receive"]))
```

I get this

```
1659605.00 Receive <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
1.660E+6 Receive All <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
print "%.2f"%column_sum["money_receive"]
1660000.00
```

But I don't understand why.

Comment: What? What were you expecting? How does your output differ?

Comment: Well i think that 1659605.00 + 0.00 = 1659605.00 not 1660000.00

Comment: It's easy enough to verify that it is - `Decimal('0.00') + Decimal('1659605.00')` is `Decimal('1659605.00')`, as you'd expect, so one of your other assumptions must be incorrect. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and cut the code down to the actual issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe

Yeah but in my production code i have round as i describe from Decimal('1659605.00') to 1.660E+6. If it was so easy i would not ask. 
In code i try to repeat production environment.

Comment: If you can't *"repeat production environment"*, we can't help you. It certainly seems like you're rounding it, but I can't tell you where or why.

Comment: You must have changed the decimal precision somewhere (the default is large enough).

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i understand. It's legacy 1k+ lines of very ugly code with lot of calls.
I found that getcontext_decimal().prec = 4  call before that piece of code.
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext as getcontext_decimal
Can this just theoretically in some way round values? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Darius - not just theoretically - that's exactly what it does. When precision is 4, the `decimal` module will round to 4 places. That's your "problem" but it may not be a problem at all. This code was written for that level of precision so its a question of whether that decision was sane or not.

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq, which discusses this

Comment: @tdelaney as i see it was very bad decision coz it's call globally and affect all Decimal's.

tdelaney interjay jonrsharpe Thank you guys for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decimal` module rounds calculations based on the precision requested in its context. If you change the default, you get the situation you describe:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> print '%f' % (decimal.Decimal('1659605.00') + decimal.Decimal('0.0'))
1659605.000000
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec=4
>>> print '%f' % (decimal.Decimal('1659605.00') + decimal.Decimal('0.0'))
1660000.000000
>>>
```

You can create a different context and use it temporarily

```
>>> ctx = decimal.Context(prec=60)
>>> oldctx = decimal.getcontext()
>>> decimal.setcontext(ctx)
>>> print '%f' % (decimal.Decimal('1659605.00') + decimal.Decimal('0.0'))
1659605.000000
>>> decimal.setcontext(oldctx)
```

or do the math in the ctx object itself

```
>>> print '%f' % ctx.add(decimal.Decimal('1659605.00'), decimal.Decimal('0.0'))
1659605.000000
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your answer before click delete)).